# How to add more than one contextual filters in drupal view?

Tags: drupal, filter, drupal-7, drupal-contextual-filters

I am working with drupal views to display news in slide show.

Now i need to add Articles along with news in a single slideshow, for this purpose i am trying to add relations and then adding those relationships to NID in contextual filters.

(Snap Shots here)

http://prntscr.com/b5jvvw

http://prntscr.com/b5jq2x

With single contextual filter every thing works perfect but on adding other nothing works.
Snap for the slide show http://prntscr.com/b5jqyu

How to add more than one contextual filters in drupal view?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking how to form page url so view would collect those contextual paremeters so, it should be like:

page_url/news_id/article_id

i.e.

slodeshow/5/17

As alternative you can use `views_embed_view()`:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7.x-3.x

and form page url as you like (need), collect them from page url manually and then call views_embed_view with those parameters and print out html content that function returned.

Parameters are: `view_machine_name, display_machine_in, first_contextuarl_filter, second_contextual_filter, thirt_contextual_filter`...